# How can I simulate tapping on touch for Android?

Tags: unity, unityscript

I'm searching on `Input.Touch` properties to find how can I simulate tapping on touch for Android. Something like `Input.getmouseButtonDown()` on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For Single Touch:

`Input.GetMouseButtonDown` also works for touch devices if you are going to implement single touch.

### For Multiple Touches:

For multiple touch, you can do something like,

```
void Update ()
{
    int activeTouches = Input.touchCount;

    if (activeTouches > 0) {
        print (activeTouches + " touch(es) detected");

        for (int i = 0; i < activeTouches; i++) {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch (i);

            print ("Touch index " + touch.fingerId + " detected at position " + touch.position);

            switch (touch.phase) {
            case TouchPhase.Began:
                print ("User did touch the screen");
                break;
            case TouchPhase.Moved:
                print ("User dragging or moving his finger");
                break;
            case TouchPhase.Ended:
                print ("User did lift up his finger");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what you mean from single touch? many fingers work in same time in my project

Comment: Single touch means 1 finger at a time.

Comment: check the edits

Comment: what about touches.tapcount==1 ?

Comment: have a look at [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-tapCount.html)

Comment: i didnt test your answer on mobile but you mean just touchphase.began just works as tapping? i accepted your answer

Comment: Yes and even `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` will work for single tap :)

Comment: can you tell me how to check mouse or touch is over a ui element? the code works well but even i push a button or radar screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37114/discussion-between-hamza-hasan-and-virtouso).

Comment: What you want actually? That touch should not work when it is over any specific thing? Or touch should go on and just want to check either it is on a specific object?

Comment: i made every where player tapped tank head rotates to that position and shoots that. but even when i touch Ui buttons it works to. i fixed it using event trigger

Comment: That is much clear and glad to hear that :)